# How to mute specific audio on headset but not on laptop/tv speakers?

Tags: laptop, audio, speakers, headphones, playstation

I am using PS4 Remote Play on my laptop that is also plugged into my TV using an HDMI cable. I have the audio coming through the headset which is plugged into the laptop via headphone jack and through the TV speakers.

I would like to know if I can mute *just* the Remote Play audio on the laptop/TV speakers but not on the headset, whist still allowing other audio to play.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no you can't.

To route each source independently to specific outputs would require considerably more sophisticated internal routing than you will find on any domestic equipment.

You could possibly do this on a Mac using a combination of [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) and [Loopback](https://rogueamoeba.com/loopback/) but that would be a $150 outlay for a one-trick pony.